# Rewrite MySQL's INSERT string in ANSI format

Tags: php, mysql, ansi-sql

I have been trying use php's preg_split to rewrite mysql's sql insert statement string into general format, for instance:
**INSERT INTO `table_name`
   SET `col1`=123, `col2`='That''s a ''test case'', and that''s too.'**

Expected Result:
**Array[0]='col1'

    Array[1]=123

    Array[2]='col2'

    Array[3]='That''s a ''test case'', and that''s too.'**

So, I can use the result array to write the sql into the following:
**Insert into table_name (col1, col2)
    values (123, 'That''s a ''test case'', and that''s too.');**

Obviously the simple function like **preg_split('/,/', $source)** won't work in all cases. I am wondering if there is any better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty Unclear what you want to achieve over here

Comment: As I mentioned in the example, I am trying to find a better way to convert MySQL's INSERT ** STATEMENT STRING** into ANSI formatted sql statement to be used in other DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
         * @param array $fields_values
         * @param string $table
         * @return string
         */
        function insertQuery(array $fields_values, $table) {
            $fields = implode(', ', array_keys($fields_values));
            $values = implode(', ', array_values($fields_values));
            return $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$fields}) VALUES ({$values})";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply but your function is for the second step. The first step is to split up all the fields and values from the sql statement string into an array.

Comment: i am not getting you. pls explain more